# Is the probability being accepted at Grad School higher for applying to $50$ colleges insted of $5$?

Tags: probability

I perform the following two experiments-

- Experiment $A$: I apply to $5$ colleges for Grad School.
- Experiment $B$: I apply to $50$ colleges for Grad School.

Is the probability of getting an admit higher for Experiment $B$? if so, why? if not, why not? How would I calculate this probability in either case?

Assume All colleges are similar in all respects (Ranking, quality of students etc.)

Comment: You can solve this with a [Bernoulli process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_process)...

Comment: Is the probability greater than 0% in either case? I had the impression that a "college" means an institution the offers only undergraduate education.

Comment: By "higher" do you mean strictly larger?  Or do you mean $\geq$?

Comment: @A.P. A Bernoulli process assumes independence.  This is certainly not the case here.

Comment: @Paul I assumed independence from "all colleges are similar in all respects", but you are right in that it might very well not be the case.

Comment: @Paul  while this is a valid point, your other comment rather suggests a certain misconception what independence mean. When I through a *biased* coin repeatedly the events are independent. If I have no information or little information how the coin is biased  observing some trials will give me information that will allow me better predictions than those I could make *a priori*; this does however not mean that the events are then not independent anymore.

Comment: The probability of getting an admit from at least one of the colleges is $1-(1-p)^n$, where $p\in[0,1]$ is the probability that a college will give you an admit, and $n\in\mathbb{N}$ is the number of colleges that you apply to. As you can see, if $p>0$ then the the probability of getting an admit from at least one of the college increases as the number of colleges that you apply to ($n$) increases.

Comment: @quid, if the acceptance/rejection by one college gives information on the probability of being accepted/rejected by another college, information which is not available by other data, than by definition they are not independent.  This is just standard Bayesian analysis.

Comment: @Paul I think we are talking sideways. It might have helped had you commented on the example I gave rather then being assertive.

Comment: @quid, in your example are assuming you have no information on the bias of a coin.  I am saying we have full information about the probability of acceptance based on the characteristics of the applicant.

Comment: @quid: By definition, acceptance to College A and acceptance to College B are independent iff $P(A) = P(A|B)$.  Paul argues (and I would tend to agree) that that is not generally the case.  Suppose I know that College B is highly selective (accepting the top 5 percent, say), and College A is only moderately selective (accepting the top 25 percent).  Then $P(A) = 0.25$, but $P(A|B) > 0.25$ almost certainly; if I've been accepted at College B, I'm almost surely going to be accepted at College A.  It's implicit in the phrases "top 5 percent" or "top 25 percent."

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I should not have said there is a misconception. However I still think there is a different conception.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you get accepted to each school independently with probability $p$, the probability you get rejected by all $n$ schools is $(1-p)^n$. Thus, the probability of getting at least $1$ acceptance is $1-(1-p)^n$. Note that if $0<p<1$, $(1-p)^n \downto 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so the probability of acceptance increases to $1$ as you increase $n$.

Comment: In this case the probabilities are certainly not independent.

Comment: Why not? He says the colleges are similar and I don't see why sending the same application to each college with the college's name changed wouldn't make it essentially i.i.d..

Comment: because math professors look at applications in a very similar way from institution to institution.  Given some GRE scores, background, and GPA, I can calculate a probability of someone getting into a school.  However, given that one school accepted or rejected an application gives me a lot of additional information on whether an application is accepted or rejected elsewhere.

Comment: Assume FERPA or similar exists. Then they're independent.

Comment: @Paul this  is true, but this information is encoded in the size of the probability $p$.

Comment: @quid that is an assumption that is not validated by experience.

Comment: Thank you guys for all the help. But I am a little confused. If suppose instead of college applications we were to toss an unbiased coin 5 times and 50 times. Would the probability of getting a heads change depending on the number of trials? I know that by Gamblers fallacy the probability is not affected but i am unable to distinguish between these 3 happenings. Why is the college app question different than the coin tossing which is again different to the gamblers fallacy? Or are these at all different? @paul you can assume the independance of a candidate getting admits from separate colleges

Answer (score 0):

The key problem here is the ambiguity inherent in the phrase "similar in all respects."  If the schools were really identical, then they'd accept not only the same number of students, but also the same *exact students*.

If we could count on the schools admitting students independently, then Batman's analysis follows.  As Paul points out, this is not generally reflective of the way school's actually admit students.  A poor applicant is likely to be rejected nearly everywhere; an excellent applicant is likely to be accepted nearly everywhere.

Absent a more precise model of how applicants are accepted at different schools, an exact answer seems impossible.  About the best one can say for sure is that the probability of being admitted *somewhere* is monotonically non-decreasing in the number of schools applied to.

One possible approach to this situation might be to assume that all applicants have a respective strength $q$, which represents their probability of being accepted at any school (thus representing the "similar in all respects" clause).  Then, for any given student, Batman's analysis can be applied.

We then consider that $q$ has a prior distribution, given by a CDF $F(Q) = P(q \leq Q)$, with PDF $f = dF/dQ$.  We might thus calculate the conditional probability of being accepted at $k$ of $50$ schools, given that we were accepted at $j$ of $5$ schools.

For instance, suppose $f$ is the uniform distribution and $j = 5$; the student was accepted at *all* of the $5$ schools.  Then the posterior distribution of $q$ is given by $g(q) = 6q^5$, and the probability of being accepted at exactly $k$ of $50$ schools (assuming the $50$ and the $5$ are mutually disjoint) is

$$
\begin{align}
P(k) & = \int_{q=0}^1 g(q) \binom{50}{k} q^k (1-q)^{50-k} \, dq \\
     & = \int_{q=0}^1 6q^5 \binom{50}{k} q^k (1-q)^{50-k} \, dq \\
     & = 6 \binom{50}{k} \int_{q=0}^1 q^{k+5} (1-q)^{50-k} \, dq \\
     & = 6 \binom{50}{k} \frac{(50-k)!(k+5)!}{56!} \\
     & = \frac{6(k+1)(k+2)(k+3)(k+4)(k+5)}
              {51 \cdot 52 \cdot 53 \cdot 54 \cdot 55 \cdot 56}
\end{align}
$$

In particular, the probability of being accepted at all $50$ schools would be $6/56 = 3/28 \doteq 0.10714$.  Different priors would of course yield different results.